# Systems of linear equations in the same modulus

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I am working with a system of linear equations all taken with the same modulus, $n$, there is no assumption on $n$ other then it is at least 3 (really don't want to assume it is prime) I don't have much experience in this type of problem so I want to make sure the following is valid, the system is

$X_a + X_b = Y_a + Y_b$

$ aX_a + bX_b = aY_a + bY_b$

Where $a$ and $b$ are both strictly less then $n$ and $a \neq b$ what I would like to do is multiply equation 1 by $a$ and subtract giving me:

$(a-b)X_b = (a-b)Y_b$

And from this I would like to conclude $X_b = Y_b$  Is this valid or am I assuming things work out easier then they actually do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are working modulo n.

Multiply both sides of a equality by a same amount ; the  equality remains valid (but
equality may  lose its consistency if we multiply by zero). 
We can
divide both members of an  equality  by the same amount if the
amount is not zero, this meaning that the amount is reversible. So for have
$X_b= Y_b$ must ensure that $a-b$ is invertible modulo n ie that
$a-b$ is not divisible by n, which is ensured by the assumption on
a,b and n, but  a and b must   be positive.
So if $m=gcd((a-b),n)$ then the solution is $X_b=Y_b+\frac{n}{m}$.

Comment: Just to make sure I get you, you are saying the first step is fine but $(a-b)X_b = (a-b)Y_b$ only implies $X_b = Y_b$ if gcd$(a-b, n)=1$?
So the easiest thing would be to assume $n$ is prime then.....

Can anything be said at all if $a-b$ and $n$ are not coprime?

Comment: we can say in this case $(-n<a-b<n and a\neq b)$, that there are two
possibilities: $a-b$ divide n then we have $X-b_=Y_b + \frac{n}{
(a-b)}.$
 Or $a-b$ does not divide n then $X_b =
Y_b $  thanks.